# FATAL EXCEPTION; SQLiteException: no such column:

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin

updateName() is working fine, but updateID() throwing error

I'm not able to find a solution

Can you please check my code to find what's wrong?

### DataBaseHandler.kt

```
val DB_NAME = "DBDEMO2"
val DB_VERSION = 1

val TABLE_NAME = "table_DEMO2"
val COL_EMP_ID = "empId"
val COL_EMP_NAME = "empName"

data class User(var id: Int, var name: String)

val list = mutableListOf<String>(
    "John", "Robert", "William", "Charles", "Mary", "Elizabeth", "Maria", "Anne", "Margaret",
    "David","James","Richard","Johann","George","Paul","Susan", "Ruth", "Anna","Alice","Dorothy")

val CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+ TABLE_NAME+"("+ COL_EMP_ID+" INTEGER, "+COL_EMP_NAME+" TEXT NOT NULL" + ")"

class DataBaseHandler(context: Context) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DB_NAME,null, DB_VERSION){

    var  db: SQLiteDatabase = writableDatabase
    fun insertData(){
        val cv = ContentValues()
        var id = 1001
        var index = 0
        for (id in 1001..1020){
            cv.put(COL_EMP_ID,id)
            cv.put(COL_EMP_NAME, list[index])
            db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,cv)
            index++
        }

    }

    fun modifyName(empID : Int, newName : String){
        val cv = ContentValues()
        cv.put(COL_EMP_NAME,newName)
        db.update(TABLE_NAME,cv, COL_EMP_ID+" = "+empID,null)
    }

    fun modifyID(name : String, newEmpID : Int){
        val cv = ContentValues()
        cv.put(COL_EMP_ID,newEmpID)
        db.update(TABLE_NAME,cv, COL_EMP_NAME+" = "+name,null)
    }

    fun deleteAllData(){
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME,null,null)
    }

    fun displayData() : List<User>{

        val list = mutableListOf<User>()
        val cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, arrayOf(COL_EMP_ID, COL_EMP_NAME),null,null,null,null,null,null)
        if (cursor!=null && cursor.count >0 ) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                val data = User(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1))
                list.add(data)
            }
        }
        cursor.close()
        return list
    }


    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {
        db?.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE)
        Log.i("TAG", "OnCreateTable")
    }

    override fun onOpen(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {
        super.onOpen(db)
        Log.i("TAG", "OnOpenTable")
    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase?, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {

    }
}
```

### MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {

lateinit var dbhandler: DataBaseHandler
lateinit var list: List<User>


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    BtnUpdateName.setOnClickListener(this)
    BtnUpdateID.setOnClickListener(this)
    buttonDispData.setOnClickListener(this)
    buttonDeleteAll.setOnClickListener(this)
    buttonInsertData.setOnClickListener(this)

    refreshList()
}


override fun onClick(v: View?) {
    when (v?.id) {
        R.id.BtnUpdateName -> updateName()
        R.id.BtnUpdateID -> updateID()
        R.id.buttonDispData -> refreshList()
        R.id.buttonDeleteAll -> deleteAll()
        R.id.buttonInsertData -> dbhandler.insertData()
    }
}

fun updateName() {
    val id = Integer.parseInt(EditTextEmpID.getText().toString())
    val newEmpName = EditTextNewEmpName.getText().toString()
    dbhandler.modifyName(id, newEmpName)
    refreshList()
}

fun updateID() {
    val name = EditTextEmpName.getText().toString()
    val newEmpID = Integer.parseInt(EditTextNewEmpID.getText().toString())
    dbhandler.modifyID(name, newEmpID)
    refreshList()
}

  fun deleteAll() {

      val dbHandlerDel = DataBaseHandler(this)
      dbHandlerDel.deleteAllData()
      refreshList()
  }

fun refreshList() {
    textDisplayResult.text = getResult()
}

fun getResult(): String {
    val dbHandlerResult = DataBaseHandler(this@MainActivity)
    list = dbHandlerResult.displayData()
    val str = StringBuffer("")
    if (list != null && list.size > 0) {
        for (element in list) {
            str.append(element.id.toString() + ", " + element.name + "\n")
        }
        return str.toString()
    } else
        return "No Items"
}
```

}

updateName() is working fine, but updateID() throwing error

> 2020-05-31 18:51:33.656 6423-6423/com.db.dbdemo2 E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.db.dbdemo2, PID: 6423
>       android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Mary (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE table_DEMO2 SET empId=? WHERE
>   empName = Mary
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native
>   Method)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.updateWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1577)
>           at
>
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.update(SQLiteDatabase.java:1525)
>               at com.db.dbdemo2.DataBaseHandler.modifyID(DataBaseHandler.kt:52)
>               at com.db.dbdemo2.MainActivity.updateID(MainActivity.kt:75)
>               at com.db.dbdemo2.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.kt:58)
>               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
>               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try by changing your `modifyID()` method as below

```
fun modifyID(name : String, newEmpID : Int){
        val cv = ContentValues()
        cv.put(COL_EMP_ID,newEmpID)
        val args = arrayOf<String>(name)
        db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, COL_EMP_NAME + "=?", args)
    }
```